# Rest client имплементация

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Клиент на Jax-rs. Требуется подать PUT заявку в формате:
http://localhost:8081/devises/:id/:ip/:status
Имеется часть кода:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget target = client.target("http://192.168.66.228:8081/api/1.0/devices/");

Response postResponce = target.request().put()
```

Подскажите как подать параметры переменых и что должно храниться в .put(.....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - просто поклеить URL конкатенацией:

```
client.target("http://192.168.66.228:8081/api/1.0/devices/" + id + "/" + "/" + ip + "/" + status);
```

Но это плохо читается, поэтому лучше воспользоваться возможностями JAX-RS API:

```
Response response = client.target("http://192.168.66.228:8081")
                          .path("api/1.0/devices")
                          .path(id)  
                          .path(ip)  
                          .path(status)  
                          .method("PUT");
```

Comment: Попробовал как написали, но в .put() требует вставить Entity class. Попробовал вот таким образом: .request().put(Entity.text(String.class));
В итоге получил ошибку: Sep 15, 2016 11:44:50 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain, type=class java.lang.Class, genericType=class java.lang.Class.

Comment: А вы уверены, что хотите именно `PUT` без тела сообщения?

Comment: Да мне просто нужно поменять статус подключеного устройства true/false
Через POSTMAN приложение все ок, просто подаю параметры по шаблону: 
http://localhost:8081/devises/:id/:ip/:status

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи, обновил ответ

Comment: Добавил пустой json в тело и все получилось. Странно... Если есть более правильный способ, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: IDE подсказывает что нет такого метода .method("PUT");

Comment: Нашел. .request().method("PUT"); Спасибо за наводку!